# Why .sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")) does not work in Chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select text in the text field and delete it. 
I use chromedriver for linux.

This is my code:

```
loginPage.getPasswordField().sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
loginPage.getPasswordField().sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

But it does not work (actually first line). Why? How to make it work?

Versions:
Chrome: Version 28.0.1500.95
ChromeDriver: chromedriver_linux64_2.1/chromedriver_linux64_2.2

Comment: Not sure.  Do you get an error?  Why not just do loginPage.getPasswordField().clear(), though?

Comment: I did not get en error. I just see that text in the field is not selected and is not deleted. I can't use clear... Because somehow my webapp works the way it does not catch the 'clear' event from webdriver... I need to check that Login button is disabled when no text is present in the field. I can achieve this via loginPage.getPasswordField().sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE); - and this works, but I want also to check the case "ctrl + a and delete"... And the latter - does not work...

Comment: Well that's the issue then. `.clear` should clear everything in the text box. No questions asked. So **don't try to patch over it**. What versions of Selenium are you using? What version of Chrome & the ChromeDriver are you using? So when you call `.clear`, what *exactly* happens?

Comment: Oh... Very very sorry for my bad explanation... `.clear` works, - my webpage does not work: after `.clear` actually clears the text field, my loginbutton still is not disabled as expected... So I try to patch my webapp, not driver:) From one side - it's not good that webapp does not catch `.clear` 'good job'... From the other... Seems like `.clear` does not do what actually user do to clear the text... So... It's hard to punish my webapp for that...

Comment: @yashaka do you get the solution for this issue? I am also looking into this issue.

Comment: @AvinashJadhav
userid.click(); 
Actions builder = new Actions(browserStackDriver); Action select = builder.keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("A").keyUp(Keys.COMMAND).build(); select.perform(); I was using Mac. Change the Command to Control for Windows and check.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use action builder?
For example, from our automation suite:

```
public void selectAndDeleteTextViaKeyboard() {
    selectTextViaKeyboard()
    deleteViaKeyboard() 
}

public void deleteViaKeyboard() {
    Actions builder = new Actions(webDriverProxy.getWebDriver());
    builder.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE)
            .release().perform();
}

public void selectTextViaKeyboard() {
    Actions builder = new Actions(webDriverProxy.getWebDriver());
    Action select= builder
            .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
            .sendKeys("a")
            .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
            .build();
    select.perform();

}
```

Comment: Thank you @johnny I had an issue where userid.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a")); was not working for Safari on MAC. The below code fixed the issue.


userid.click();
                    Actions builder = new Actions(browserStackDriver);
                    Action select = builder.keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("A").keyUp(Keys.COMMAND).build();
                    select.perform();

Answer (score 1):

```
public void copyToClipbord(String copyTo)
{
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection str = new StringSelection(copyTo);
    clipboard.setContents(str, null );
}

public void setText(WebElement element, String value)
{
    copyToClipbord(value);
    element.click();
    element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"), "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
 webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));
 webElement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), Keys.DELETE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loginPage.getPasswordField().clear
```

Comment: When answering questions it is best to explain in more detail so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site.