# Selecting text in ckeditor through Selenium webdriver java code

Tags: selenium

I am new to both ckeditor as well as Selenium
Well in the web application where I work is similar to ckeditor

I have written the code through selenium where I have to enter the text in the editor but now my requirement is to select the all text which I have entered.
I am not able to select that text.
Anyone knowing the solution for it.Do let me know.

```
    WebElement iframe1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe1);
    WebElement web1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='p']"));
    web1.clear();
    Actions act1=new Actions(driver);
    act1.sendKeys(web1, "Hello");
```

Comment: Look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319547/why-sendkeyskeys-chordkeys-control-a-does-not-work-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to select the content from editor so that I can format these text using format tool bar

You should try as below to select all text content from editor :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset")));

WebElement body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));

//Now select all text content from editor
body.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"))

//Now after entering text into texteditor switch back to default content
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

//Now perform action to format the text content
```